# Week() function in sql script

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am using sql server 2005. I just want to know is there something we can get the week number for the particular month. Example `Date = '2008-10-16'` Is there something we can have `SELECT WEEK(Date)`. Or any better suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select (datepart(dd,'2008-10-08')-1) / 7 + 1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT DATEPART( week, '2008-10-16')
```

Comment: Is there a way i can get week for the month. Is gives me 42 i guess thats the week of the year.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way:

```
SET @weeksinmonth=datediff(week, @date, @lastdate) + 1
```

That is a copy-and-paste out of one of my stored procedures.